# Array of index values for unique elements in list

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, unique

I have the following list:

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

with `np.unique` values of `[1, 2]`

How do I generate the following list:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

i.e. a running index from 1 for each of the unique elements in the list `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`pandas.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) after grouping by the value itself, it does exactly that:

> Number each item in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

places = list(pd.Series(x).groupby(by=x).cumcount().values + 1)
print(places)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this with out pandas?

Comment: @alex_lewis I tried with native numpy function but couldn't get any nice solution. the other way I think of is using `list.index` in a loop, which will be 100x times slower :( maybe someon else will come up with something numpy only.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `return_counts=True` of `np.unique` with listcomp and `np.hstack`. It is still faster pandas solution

```
c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)[1]
np.hstack([np.arange(item)+1 for item in c])

Out[869]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: this will only work if the values are consecutive. for `x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])` you'll get `[1 2 3 1 2 3]`  while you should be getting `[1 2 1 2 3 3]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this is any faster or slower solution, but if you need just a list result with no pandas, you could try this

```
arr = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from collections import Counter
ranges = [range(1,v+1) for k,v in Counter(arr).items()]
result = []
for l in ranges:
    result.extend(list(l))
print(result)
```

> > [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]

(or make your own counter with `dict` instead of `Counter()`)